# The geometry and arithmetic of the intersection of a cubic and quadric threefold

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory

Let $f,g \in \mathbb{Z}[x_0, \cdots, x_4]$ be a quadratic and cubic form (i.e., homogeneous polynomials) respectively, and let $V(f), V(g)$ denote their respective projective varieties; $V(f), V(g)$ are respectively a quadric and a cubic threefold.

Is anything known about the geometry or arithmetic of the intersection of the variety $V(f) \cap V(g)$? Indeed, are the rational points on $V(f) \cap V(g)$ expected to be Zariski dense?

Comment: If I haven't miscalculated, such intersections (when smooth) are exactly the genus $4$ K3 surfaces. So probably potential density is expected but unproven except in special cases (covered by Bogomolov-Tschinkel).

Comment: @dhy I think what you said is correct... indeed, the typical intersection of a quadric and a cubic in $\mathbb{P}^4$ is a genus 4 K3 surface. If you write that as an answer I will accept it.